# How to sort date array with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort the date array. It does perfectly. But May 4 is listed in the last element of the array which is wrong. Could you help me to resolve this?

```
var listOfString = "2016-05-24|Failed,2016-05-04|Failed,2016-04-19|Passed,2016-04-15|Passed,2016-06-01|Failed";
        var arrayStrings = listOfString.split(',');
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayStrings.length; i++) {
            dateArray[count++] = new Date(arrayStrings[i].split('|')[0]);
        }
        dateArray.sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
            alert(dateArray[i]);
        }
```

Output received as

```
Fri Apr 15 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Apr 19 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue May 24 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Wed Jun 01 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Wed May 04 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: Since they are already in y-m-d order with preceding zeroes, why not just sort as strings? Also use `console.log` to see the result, alerts are not a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the values as strings in descending order (y-m-d) and with preceding zeroes it means they are sortable also as strings. You don't need to do any conversions in this case, just sort as a string array after split.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
var listOfString = "2016-05-24|Failed,2016-05-04|Failed,2016-04-19|Passed,2016-04-15|Passed,2016-06-01|Failed";
        var arrayStrings = listOfString.split(',');
        var dateArray = new Array();
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayStrings.length; i++) {
            dateArray[count++] = arrayStrings[i].split('|')[0];
        }
        dateArray.sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(dateArray[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your `date.sort()` to this

```
    dateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a-b;
    });
```

Returns

```
VM126:57 Fri Apr 15 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
VM126:57 Tue Apr 19 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
VM126:57 Wed May 04 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
VM126:57 Tue May 24 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
VM126:57 Wed Jun 01 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

You assumed that `.sort()` would automatically handle dates but unfortunately, that's not the case. It either does `alphabetical` or `numerical` sort only and that was the result you had. To fix, I added a callback function that will determine if an item is ahead or behind in the order in the bubble sort and subtracting dates returns the number of seconds between the two dates and that would be a number and easy to subtract and return the difference in the sort.